# Addition Register Machine

Tags: computation-models

In an abstract [register machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_machine), is it possible to add two registers together without losing one of the summands, but without using a third register?

That is to have a register machine that maps $(m,n)\mapsto (m,m+n)$ that only uses two registers to store $m$ and $n$.

Disclaimer I am a mathematician and don't know much computer science. Also I didn't know what tag to put on this so apologies if this ends up in the wrong section.

Comment: That depends on whether or not such operation is allowed in your definition (usually, it is). If you are a mathematician as you say, you shouldn't be afraid to look up a definition.

Comment: @TEMLIB This question is about a [class of abstract machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_machine), not about physical devices.